# GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available

Tags: apt, 22.04

May I please get some directions towards fixing the problem below?

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. 
GPG error: https://pkg.osquerypackages.com/deb deb
InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 97A80C63C9D8B80B
enter code here
```

Ubuntu version is 22.04 and the instructions I used or commands are:

```
sudo gpg --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C
sudo apt update
```

some contents from the sudo-apt-cache policy

```
00 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-backports,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-backports,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
```

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! What instructions did you follow to install the repository? It would help to post a link to the instructions. Also, which version of Ubuntu are you using? If you could please edit your question and add the extra information (and add the Ubuntu version in the tags), this will help people answer your question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi mchid, thank you for yur reply. I just included some more information such as version number and commands I used.

Comment: I request you to add the output of `sudo apt-cache policy` to the question.

Comment: Hello Rishon and thank you for your suggestion. I edited the question by including some of the contents from the command you provided.

Comment: With my knowledge base, i can't find anything wrong here. Do you mind linking the article?

Comment: Linking the article? DO forgive me, I am still trying to find my feet in Linux.

Comment: Your keys are different. You added 871920D1991BC93C but it's asking for 97A80C63C9D8B80B. Are you sure this is correct? Where did you obtain 871920D1991BC93C from?

Comment: Also, what version are you trying to install? The [current version](https://osquery.io/downloads/official/5.9.1) shows a different method of managing the keys. I could easily provide an answer on how to apply these instructions to fix the current problem but we would need to know like what you did to install the current one. Did you use an `add-apt-repository` command? If so, what was it? You can use the up arrow key to go through your previous commands and I think you can even search for previous commands in the terminal by using CTRL+R and then type in `sudo add-apt-repository`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it looks like you were possibly following the instructions for an older version of Ubuntu or older version of the software.

I found installation instructions for the current version by reading [the documentation here](https://osquery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/install-linux/) which provided a link to the [download page](https://osquery.io/downloads/official/5.9.1).

Near the bottom of the downloads page, I then clicked on **Debian Linux** under **Alternative Install Options** to reveal the commands needed to add the repository. Ubuntu is based on Debian Linux and both use the same "apt" or "deb" based package manager so Debian should be equivalent to Ubuntu here.

But first, you will need to remove the existing repository from your sources list so run the following commands:

```
sudo sed -i '/osquerypackages/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo sed -i '/osquerypackages/d' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Then, simply follow the instructions:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -L https://pkg.osquery.io/deb/pubkey.gpg | sudo tee /etc/apt/keyrings/osquery.asc
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/osquery.asc] https://pkg.osquery.io/deb deb main'
sudo apt install osquery
```